# Calculate Windows Form Width for Displayed Text

Tags: .net, winforms, forms, graphics, textrenderer

I need to calculate Windows Form Width for displayed text.
The form width is obviously in pixels so you would just want to obtain the width of the text in pixels but this doesn't work:

```
animationForm.Width = TextRenderer.MeasureText(_caption, animationForm.Font).Width;
```

The calculated form width is way too small (cuts off text) - what is going on here?
MeasureText uses pixels, form width is in pixels.

This works better but I don't think is right:

```
animationForm.Width = (int)(_caption.Length * animationForm.Font.Size);
```

Help would be appreciated.

AnimationPic - PictureBox,
Caption is set on a Label

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace PrlSystems.MaimInvoicing.Forms
{
    public partial class ProgressIndicatorForm : Form
    {
        private volatile bool _animating = false;
        private Form _parent;
        private string _caption = "";

        private object _mutex = new object();

        public ProgressIndicatorForm(Form parent)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            _parent = parent;
        }

        public string Caption
        {
            set { _caption = value; }
            get { return _caption; }
        }

        public void StartAnimation()
        {
            lock (_mutex)
            {
                if (!_animating)
                {
                    if (_parent != null)
                    {
                        _parent.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor;
                        _parent.Enabled = false;
                    }

                    _animating = true;
                    _SpawnAnimationThread();
                }
            }
        }

        public void StopAnimation()
        {
            lock (_mutex)
            {
                if (_animating)
                {
                    _animating = false; // stop animation thread

                    if (_parent != null)
                    {
                        // restore parent form UI
                        _parent.Cursor = Cursors.Default;
                        _parent.Enabled = true;
                        _parent.Activate();
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private void _SpawnAnimationThread()
        {
            Thread animationThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(_Animate));
            animationThread.Priority = ThreadPriority.Normal;
            animationThread.IsBackground = true;    // should terminate when application ends
            animationThread.Start();
        }

        private void _Animate()
        {
            ProgressIndicatorForm animationForm = new ProgressIndicatorForm(_parent);
            animationForm.CaptionLabel.Text = _caption;
            animationForm.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
            animationForm.TopMost = true;
            animationForm.Width = _CalculateFormWidth(animationForm);

            animationForm.Show();

            while (_animating)
            {
                animationForm.CaptionLabel.Text = _caption;
                animationForm.Width = _CalculateFormWidth(animationForm);

                animationForm.BringToFront();
                animationForm.Refresh();
            }
            animationForm.Close();
            animationForm.Dispose();
        }

        private int _CalculateFormWidth(ProgressIndicatorForm animationForm)
        {
            int width = AnimationPic.Location.X + AnimationPic.Width +
                TextRenderer.MeasureText(_caption, animationForm.Font).Width;


            return width;
        }
    }
}
```

Image in the designer:

[image: This is how it looks in the designer, the progress dialog]

Comment: I am going to clarify something that I left out but it will matter. I also have an animation pic. Here's the entire formula: int width = AnimationPic.Location.X + AnimationPic.Width + TextRenderer.MeasureText(_caption, animationForm.Font).Width;

Answer (score 4):

Rather than `Form.Width`, you need to use [**`Form.ClientSize.Width`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9278sfx2.aspx).

The latter will return the actual width of the form's **client area**; i.e., the place where you can draw stuff. From the Remarks section in the documentation:

> The size of the client area of the form is the size of the form excluding the borders and the title bar. The client area of a form is the area within a form where controls can be placed. You can use this property to get the proper dimensions when performing graphics operations or when sizing and positioning controls on the form. To get the size of the entire form, use the [`Size` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.size.aspx) or use the individual properties [`Height`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.height.aspx) and [`Width`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.width.aspx).

Contrast that with `Form.Width` (or `Form.Size.Width`), which returns the *entire* width of the form as it appears on the screen, including superfluous stuff in the non-client area, like window borders. Definitely don't waste any time trying to calculate and remove the dimensions for these items manually; it's already been done for you.

---

Using the following code:

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnPaint(e);

    string longStringOfText = "This is a really long string of text we're using for testing purposes.";

    // Resize the form's client area, keeping the same height, but
    // changing the width to match that needed to draw the text.
    this.ClientSize = new Size(TextRenderer.MeasureText(longStringOfText,
                                                        this.Font).Width,
                               ClientSize.Height);

    // Then draw in the text.
    TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics,
                          longStringOfText,
                          this.Font,
                          Point.Empty,
                          Color.Purple);
}
```

I get this:

[image: Form, with text string correctly fit across it]

Looks pretty good to me...

Comment: @Frosty: What's your point? Did I use the word "called" instead of "set"? My bad, I'll fix it. Of course, the point is still the same. You need to set the size of the **client area**, not the size of the entire form (including the non-client area).

Comment: Guys, this is animation dialog without any borders so it doesn't really matter. Nevertheless, whether I use client area or not I still lose (is cut-off because width is too short) 40% of the text.

Comment: @ActiveX: I can't imagine what the problem is. This works perfectly for me... Update your question with the code you've tried involving the `ClientSize` property.

Comment: I am going to clarify something that I left out but it will matter. I also have an animation pic. Here's the entire formula:  int width = AnimationPic.Location.X + AnimationPic.Width +
    TextRenderer.MeasureText(_caption, animationForm.Font).Width;

Comment: I have posted entire code in my original post, above. I am only interested in the width since that can only change.

Comment: @ActiveX: Did you look at the updates to my answer? This solution works perfectly for me. The width of the form snaps perfectly to fit the text. I'm not sure I understand what more you're looking for.

Comment: Hi Cody, my bad I noticed stack overflow hides longer list of comments - I missed your response since it was hidden from the view! Anyway, if you use the code above with layout as such: |__ [pic] label __| does it still work for you? The underscores signify spaces (indent 30 pixels place pic followed by label) and the pipe symbol form boundaries.

Answer (score 0):

You also need to take account the extra sizes such as width of the form. Space around the label(if you are using label?)

Comment: But definitely don't try to do this manually. Use the property explicitly provided for this purpose.

Comment: Yes, I am using a label ... The drastic loss (is cut-off) of text tells me there's something else wrong. I posted entire code above.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried specifying device context?
Try this method overload `MeasureText(IDeviceContext, String, Font, Size)`.

When you use `Form.Width`, the width contains also width of the window border. Try this:

```
animationForm.ClientSize.Width = TextRenderer.MeasureText(_caption, animationForm.Font).Width;
```

Comment: I struggle to imagine how the device context could possibly be relevant here.

Comment: Is AnimationPic placed directly on the form or is it in some container?

Comment: @ActiveX Could you send a screenshot of the form in design mode?

Comment: Directly on the form. The form style is FixedDialog, no max,min, buttons etc. How do I send you an email here? I am new to stack overflow.

Comment: @ActiveX: You don't need an email. You can attach an image directly in your question. See [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91716/how-to-upload-screenshots) for details.

Comment: Odd, best would be if you had the actual code. Try indent animation pic (27 pixels) and then place caption label beside it. So you have: |__ [pic] label __|

Comment: I have added picture to the post sorry for the delay.